# P values in Statistics

Tags: statistics

I understand that a p-value is the probability of random chance generated the data or something rarer

In the case of 4 heads and 1 Tails for 5 coin flips
Why is the p value the P(4H1T) + P(4T1H) + P(5H) + P(5T)?
Why select events which are rarer or equal to 4H1T?

Comment: A p-value can be thought of as the probability of rejecting the null hypothesis. A null hypothesis is assuming that there is no difference between observed and expected events. Hence, the p-value is the likelihood that something at least as extreme as your considered event will occur.

Comment: https://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics-2/how-to-correctly-interpret-p-values

Comment: Makes no sense to talk about P-value without specifying null and alternative hypotheses. Null because it provides the probability distribution to be used and alternative because it gives meaning to the word 'extreme'.